# Child Users (Employee) comes under list of Parent User (Business) using Ultimate member WordPress Plugin

Tags: roles

After registering to the form "Business" account gets generated, then hey can add their employees to the site.

The problem is I don't want Business to see each other, Business can see their profile and employess only which thet have added.

Business1 can not see the Business2 account and their employess.

PS: I am using Ultimate membership plugin

Here is the page I need help https://zeazo.com/members/

I have search a lot the roles are generatin via registration form of Ultimate Membership It can be hundreds of "Business Users" then they will add their employees how can we list employess unders their Buisiness and no other Business can see other Business employess.